# How to parse a string without losing plus sign in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing

I am parsing HTML strings to get values in PHP and write them in database. Here is an example string:

```
<b>Adress:</b> 22 Examplary road, Nowhere <br>
<b>Phone:</b>  +371 12345678, +371 23456789<br>
<b>E-mail: </b>info@example.com<br>
```

The string can be formatted in random manners. It can contain additional keys that I am not parsing out and it can contain duplicate keys. It can also contain only some of the keys that I am interested in or be completely empty. HTML can also be broken (example tag: `<br`). I have decided that I will follow the rules that entries are separated by `\n` and are in the form `key: value` + some HTML.

First, I use this code to make the string parseable:

```
$parse = strip_tags($string);
$parse = str_replace(':', '=', $parse);
$parse = str_replace("\n", '&', $parse);
$parse = str_replace("\r", '', $parse);
$parse = str_replace("\t", '', $parse);
```

My string looks something like this now:

```
Adress= 22 Examplary road, Nowhere&Phone=  +123 12345678, +123 23456789&E-mail= info@example.com
```

Then I use `parse_str()` to get the values and then I take out the values if the needed keys are found:

```
        parse_str($parse, $values);

        $address = null;
        if (isset($values['Adress']))
            $address = trim($values['Adress']);

        $phone = null;
        if (isset($values['Phone']))
            $phone = trim($values['Phone']);
```

The problem is that I end up with `$phone = '371 12345678, 371 23456789'` - I lose the `+` signs. How to conserve those?

Also, if you have any hints how to improve this procedure, I would be glad to know that. Some entries have `Website: example.com`, others have `Web Site example.com`... I am pretty sure that it will not be possible to automatically parse all of the information but I am looking for the best possible solution.

### Solution

Using tips provided by WEBjuju I am now using this:

```
preg_match_all('/([^:]*):\s?(.*)\n/Usi', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$values = [];
foreach ($matches as $match)
{
    $key = strip_tags($match[1]);
    $key = trim($key);
    $key = mb_strtolower($key);
    $key = str_replace("\s", '', $key);
    $key = str_replace('-', '', $key);

    $value = strip_tags($match[2]);
    $value = trim($value);

    $descriptionValues[$key] = $value;
}
```

This allows me to go from this input:

```
<b>Venue:</b> The Hall<br
<b>Adress:</b> 22 Examplary road, Nowhere <br>
<b>Phone:</b>  +371 12345678<br>
<b>E-mail: </b>info@hkliepaja.lv<br>
<b>Website:</b> <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">example.com</a><br>
```

To a nice PHP array with homogenized and hopefully recognizable keys:

```
[
    'venue' => 'The Hall',
    'adress' => '22 Examplary road, Nowhere',
    'phone' => '+371 12345678',
    'email' => 'info@example.com',
    'website' => 'example.com',
];
```

It still doesn't account for the cases of missing colons, but I don't think I can solve that...

Comment: @Andy Lester, I'm not sure I agree with your retagging...

Comment: I read the description that the `html-parsing` tag is extraction of data from HTML code so I added the tag (seemed to fit the actual case). If that was reserved for something like website parsing I have no problem to go on without the tag.

Comment: I removed it because OP is not actually parsing any HTML.  Go ahead and put it back if you want.

Comment: OH I SEE! the OP is trying to scrape data. Instead of using regular expressions the methodology here is to expect the html to match up in a way such that the series of str_replaces produce something simliar to a key-var encoded_string!  i'm going to just start a new solution rather than leave all those comments on the solution that misunderstood what the OP was actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizing that you have **preformed HTML** that **conforms to a simple standard structure** I can tell you that regular expression matching will be the best way to grab this data.  Here is an example to get you on your way - I'm sure it doesn't solve everything, but it solves what your issue is on this post, where you are troubled with "finding key/var matches".

```
// now go get those matches!
preg_match_all('/<b>([^:]*):\s?<\/b>(.*)<br>/Usi', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
die('<pre>'.print_r($matches,true));
```

That will output, for instance, something like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <b>Adress:</b> 22 Examplary road, Nowhere <br>
        [1] => Adress
        [2] =>  22 Examplary road, Nowhere
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => <b>Phone:</b>  +371 12345678, +371 23456789<br>
        [1] => Phone
        [2] =>   +371 12345678, +371 23456789
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => <b>E-mail: </b>info@example.com<br>
        [1] => E-mail
        [2] => info@example.com
    )
```

And from there, I'd have to guess that you can putt that in for par.

Comment: Thank you, this is much closer to what I need. I will try going with `/([^:]*):\s?(.*)\n/Usi` because the HTML there sometimes does not conform to structure that well. I trust newlines and colons the most in this dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Use [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) before you put your value in your string. In the code where you receive this string, use [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) to get it back.

**page1.php**

```
$string = '&Adress='.base64_encode('22 Examplary road, Nowhere').'&Phone='.base64_encode('+123 12345678, +123 23456789').'&Email='.base64_encode('info@example.com');
// string is sent via curl or some other transport to page2.php
```

**page2.php**

```
parse_str($string);
echo base64_decode($Adress); // 22 Examplary road, Nowhere
echo base64_decode($Phone); // +123 12345678, +123 23456789
echo base64_decode($Email); // info@example.com
```

Comment: Your answer is basically a comment. Why not provide some code?

Comment: Do you mean I should encode it when constructing the initial string? If so, that's not possible - these strings are legacy data and are not created by me.

Comment: i mean where you say "My string looks something like this now:" and then you print what should be key value pairs of urlencoded data...but your data isn't url encoded.  and even if it is, you're better off base64 encoding it.

Comment: But these encodings makes me unable to parse it. Both `urlencode` and `base64_encode` encodes the `&` and `=` which are needed to parse the string into `key => value` array...

Comment: @juris only encode the values ---- `&key=".base64_encode($value)`

Comment: Sorry, I think I miss some trick here as this seems to recursively bring me to the parsing problem. I would have to parse string to get `$value` to encode. But finding values is the actual task - if I could easily find the `$value` to encode, I could probably use it directly without even using `parse_str()`.

Comment: is it the same codebase that is making the string and then parsing the string?? yes, stop doing that ;)  there is no need to make a url string and than parse it back out unless you are crossing http streams somewhere

Comment: As I said in the first comment - these strings are already existing descriptions in the database. They are not made by code. They are written by people over long period of time and can contain any errors. I need to parse them so I could write the values in seperate fields in a more tidy database.

Comment: @juris right, my error, i honestly don't follow what you are trying to accomplish; however, if you are trying to send data from one page to another and need to put your key/variable pairs in a parsable string, take a look at my page1.php/page2.php example which should clarify base64 usage

Comment: @mike done - base64 example posted - honestly, i think at this point the user is not passing the string from one page to another, i think it is confusion on what parse_str is used for.